# How to register route in Blueprint - <packageScan> does not work

Tags: apache-camel

How to register Java DSL route with Blueprint?

Tried:  in blueprint but it did register the route.

Error: org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectConsumerNotAvailableException: No consumers available on endpoint: direct://getPersonAddress.

### **Here is Java Route:**

```
package sms.person.address.routes;

import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;

public class PersonAddressGetRoute extends RouteBuilder {

     public final static String ROUTE_ID = "getPersonAddrRoute";

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        from("direct:getPersonAddress").routeId("ROUTE_ID")
            .routeDescription("Return address for given personId")
            .log("Getting person address")
            .setBody().simple("Get Person Address")
            .to("mock:end");
    }
}
```

---

### blueprint.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
    xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint"
    xmlns:cm="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/camel-blueprint.xsd">
    <cm:property-placeholder id="defaultProp"
        persistent-id="sms.psn.service">
        <cm:default-properties>
            <!-- Default value -->
            <cm:property name="app.http.host" value="0.0.0.0"/>
            <cm:property name="app.http.portNumber" value="9000"/>
            <cm:property name="app.url.contextPath" value="/sms/person/v1"/>
            <cm:property name="app.url.address" value="/address"/>
        </cm:default-properties>
    </cm:property-placeholder>
    <camelContext id="sms.psn.address.service" useMDCLogging="true"
        xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">

        <camel:packageScan>
            <package>sms.psn.address.routes</package>
        </camel:packageScan>

        <restConfiguration component="jetty" host="{{app.http.host}}" port="{{app.http.portNumber}}"/>
        <rest id="restPersonAddress" path="{{app.url.contextPath}}">
            <get id="getPersonAddress" uri="{{app.url.address}}">
                <to uri="direct:getPersonAddress"/>
            </get>      
        </rest>
    </camelContext>
</blueprint>
```

---

Did I missed something?